# Flask logs not showing up in GCP log viewer

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, stackdriver

I've developed a simple flask web app and deployed it to a GCP compute engine. Using gunicorn I can run the program and it works. I followed this guide https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python to set up logging.

```
import google.cloud.logging
import logging

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

client.setup_logging()

logging.info('PROGRAM STARTED')
```

This code snippet from my app appears to be working. I see the "program started" log in the log viewer. My problem is I cannot find any logs from flask such as the http requests or errors. I'm trying to understand how this works, as I'm new to both GCP and logging practices. Any tips or hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first step is to verify that Stackdriver logging is setup correctly on your VM instance. Login via an SSH shell and run this command `logger "Hello Stackdriver"`. Wait a few minutes and verify that the message appears in Stackdriver. Add a comment once you have the results.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/jvwIesM.png it appears that got logged twice

Comment: That command  confirms that Stackdriver is setup and working. Your problem is most likely the logging level. You can change the level of logging with this statement `logging.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`. There are many configuration settings, read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing both of these at the same time? If you wish to use python's built-in logging, then just have

```
import logging
```

create a logger, named for each python module it is deployed into, with

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and use it (minimally) with

```
logger.info('my log entry')
```

There's lots of configuration, filtering, etc on this through the documentation.
I cannot comment on the Google logger, but they do say to use either it or the regular python logger.

The following is an example of how to capture all or (more likely a selection) of flask's http interations (although maybe more complex than you need):

```
@app.before_request
def log_request_info():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if not current_user.is_superuser and \
                not any([(term in str(request)) for term in ['static', 'favicon', 'images']]):
            app.logger.info('%s, %s' % (
                str(current_user), request.url[len(request.url_root):][:50]))
    else:
        if not any([(term in str(request)) for term in ['api', 'static', 'favicon']]):
            app.logger.info('unauthorised: %s' % (request.url[len(request.url_root):]))
```

Note: there is a more powerful alternative to this: the filtering option to the logger construction.